# Create DataFrame from diagonal of other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a covariance matrix for two stocks in a pandas DataFrame and would like to create a dataframe that has only the diagonal of that matrix.

The matrix looks like this:

```
        AAPL        GM
AAPL    0.079894    0.034113
GM      0.034113    0.060838
```

And I would like a DataFrame with indexes `[AAPL, GM]` and a column called `covariance` or something that would look like this:

```
        covariance      
AAPL    0.079894    
GM      0.060838
```

Is there a simple way to do this or will I end up writing for loops to fill other data structures to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) to select the diagonal of the dataframe, then with with [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor to create your desired output:

```
df_diag = pd.DataFrame(data=np.diag(df), columns=['covariance'], index=df.index)
```

**Output**

```
      covariance
AAPL    0.079894
GM      0.060838
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
result = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, data=df.lookup(df.index, df.columns), columns=['covariance'])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
      covariance
AAPL    0.079894
GM      0.060838
```